# PlasticSCM: Commit all changes to partial workspace including new and deleted files?

Tags: command-line, plasticscm

I'd looking for a command line for automation to commit all changes made to a partial work space including file additions and deletions.

> cm checkin "path" --all

works on non-partial work spaces and includes new and deleted files

AND

> cm partial checkin "path" --applychanged

works for partial work spaces but not on the new or deleted files.

Since "cm partial" doesn't have the --all keyword available, I'm hoping there is a work around where plastic will include all files changed, added or deleted in a partial work space.

Any ideas?

HELP PRINT OUT FOR "CM PARTIAL CHECKIN"

> Commit changes to the repository.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> cm partial checkin | ci [<item_path>+] [-c=str_comment]
> [--applychanged] [--keeplock] [--silent] [--dropconflicts]
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> item_path           Items to be checked-in, separated by spaces. Quotes (")
>                     can be used to specify paths containing spaces.
>                     Use . to apply checkin to current directory.
> -c                  Specifies a comment to the changeset created in the
>                     checkin operation.
> --applychanged      Applies the checkin operation to the changed items
>                     detected in the workspace along with the checked out
>                     items.
> --keeplock          Keeps the lock of the locked items after the checkin
>                     operation.
> --silent            Does not show any output.
> --ignorefailed      Any changes that cannot be applied (because the lock
>                     - a.k.a. exclusive checkout - cannot be adquired or because
>                     local changes are in conflict with the server
>                     changes) are discarded and the checkin operation
>                     continues without them.
> ```
>
> Remarks:
>
> ```
> - If <item_path> is not specified, the checkin will involve all the
> pending changes in the workspace.
> - The checkin operation is always applied recursively from the given path.
> - To checkin an item:
> - The item must be under source code control.
> - The item must be checked out.
> - If the item is changed but not checked out the --applychanged flag has
> to be specified.
>
> Revision content should be different from previous revision in order to be
> checked in.
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> cm partial checkin file1.txt file2.txt
> (Applies the checkin to file1.txt and file2.txt checked-out files.)
>
> cm partial checkin .
> (Applies checkin to current directory.)
>
> cm partial ci file1.txt -c="my comment"
> (Applies the checkin to file1.txt and includes a comment.)
>
> cm partial checkin --applychanged
> (Applies the checkin to all pending changes in the workspace.)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a specific command in partial workspaces for locally added and deleted files, but you can use the next workaround in your partial workspaces:

1) `cm findprivate | cm partial add -`

2) `cm status --localdeleted --short | cm rm -`

3) `cm partial checkin`